# Is it possible to have a Thor method that is not an explicit task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thor

I have a Thor script that uses several methods

```
class Update < Thor
   desc "do_it", "a simple task"
   def do_it
     puts i_did_it
   end
   
   # no desc here !!!
   def i_did_it
     "I did it"
   end 
end
```

Is this possible? Without an explicit task, the tasks list can't be built correctly.

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be possible... is there a problem that you're encountering?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to use the no_tasks block for this.

```
class Update < Thor
   desc "do_it", "a simple task"
   def do_it
     puts i_did_it
   end

   # no desc here !!!
   no_tasks do
    def i_did_it
      "I did it"
    end
   end 
end
```

Comment: I am not sure 100% sure but I think private methods are not exposed either.

Comment: Private methods will also work I guess, but that approach does not communicate the intention very well,...

Answer (score 2):

I tried this in 2018, no_tasks didn't work for me (maybe it is replaced with the following now):

As per Thor advice

```
 Call desc if you want this method to be available as command or declare it inside a no_commands{} block.
```

So you can put the methods that you don't want to show for the CLI in a  no_commands block as follows:

```
 # no_commands is used to not show this as a command in our CLI gem

  no_commands { 
   # no desc here !!!
   # put here the methods that you don't want to show in your CLI

    def i_did_it
      "I did it"
    end

}
```